# How to run multiple session while scanning application through Burp?

Tags: java, cookies, session-management, burp-suite

While scanning an application through Burp, I've found that if I use multiple threads, it results to session errors like *The requested session id appears to be invalid. You may have more than one Task Manager window/tab open*.

But if I use single thread, the scanning is slow.

Can anyone explain me how to assign different session IDs to different threads so that I can scan through multiple threads? Is it possible to use multiple threads with multiple distributed cookies to these threads using Cookie Jars?

Comment: That's actually quite interesting. Have you considered running multiple instances of Burp?

Comment: Lucas, running two burp application will slow down my machine and it will not serve my purpose of having a fast scan then I will have two slow scanning running simultaneously on a slow machine

Answer (score 3):

This is ultimate answer by none other than **Dafydd Stuttard**  when I posted this question on portswigger support forum:

> *Dafydd Stuttard Jan 12, 2015 10:58AM UTC Support Center agent*
>
> It sounds like the application is not willing to support multiple
>   concurrent requests in the same session (for this particular function,
>   at least).
>
> Burp only currently has a single cookie jar, so you can’t do a scan
>   with multiple threads using different cookie jars, sorry.
>
> One possible solution would be to create an extension that handles
>   sessions, and maintain your own separate cookie jars and use one per
>   thread. Or you could run multiple instance of Burp, each running
>   single threaded, and scan different parts of the application with each
>   one.

Comment: Can anyone tell How to achieve the solution involved with extension? Where can I get tutorial to write my extension to do the above task

Comment: According to this: https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/questions/16318844-multiple-cookie-jars & this: http://forum.portswigger.net/thread/1589/macro-multiple-cookies-same-name along with your thread at PortSwigger, I think an extension cannot have support for this until a ported support is added to Burp Suite itself.