# Burp warning whenever I write a rule?

Tags: web-scanners, burp-suite

Whenever I write rule and save it in burp it gives this warning, I am not able to find out why it warns me

The rule is not in-scope for any URLs. Are you sure yu want to proceed?

While the rule is in the scope!

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I tried to add a rule to check whether the session is valid or not if not it will run a macro (calls the login page with userid and passwd)

Comment: Need more info to debug it really - can you anonymize the URLs and then post the scope settings & rule?

Comment: My bad, I found the problem my login page was out of the scope that's why I was getting the warning(I am so silly).  Thanks to @darkf realized my error.

Comment: @darkf -- can you help me with this [http://security.stackexchange.com/q/77545/55731]